# How do I create rotating images in jquery or javascript like this one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

http://www.lynda.com/

When mouse hovers on one of the topics listed on lynda.com webpage, the image rotates.

How can I create this interaction from jquery or javascript? 
Is there a way to see script source code from Inspect Element on the browser?

Thank you,

Comment: just right-click on the page, choose "View page source"

Comment: they probably use JS/jQuery to change `transform: rotate` together with `transform: perspective` or something

Comment: could you try lynda.com without the extension? It redirects visitors to a different page (course browser).

Comment: see http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/flip/ or http://davidwalsh.name/demo/css-flip.php for the same using css animations..

Comment: http://www.webstuffshare.com/2012/07/portfolio-flipping-slider-using-jquery-css3/

Answer (score 0):

Use the browse Mozilla Firefox and Install the Add-ons **FireBug**.

Through that you can Inspect each and every element in the page. Also you can view the scripts, styles on the page.[image: FireBug installed mozilla]

Answer (score 0):

## [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/qarasavujepu/1/edit)

Use pure css is more appropriate.

```
.content{
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;

  text-align: center;
  line-height: 500px;
  font-size:100px;
}
.first,.second{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 1s;
  background: #fec;
}
.second{
  transform:scale(-1,1);
  z-index: -1;
}
.content:hover .first{
  transform:scale(-1,1);
}
.content:hover .second{
  transform:scale(1,1);
  z-index: 0;
}
```